# JAVAFX How to update checkbox deselect after change?

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx, checkbox

Hi I am trying to write a JavaFX GUI application that allows the user to pick a set of pizza toppings using a set of check boxes. Assuming each topping cost 50 cents, and a plain pizza costs $10, display the cost of the pizza. Note that, once a topping is checked or unchecked, the cost of pizza should update automatically. I almost have it working but when I click multiple boxes the price changes, I am trying to + 0.50 cents per topping and if I de select check box -0,50 cents, but when I choose multiple check box it is adding more. How can I change this thanks.

```
import javafx.scene.control.CheckBox;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;


public class PizzaMenu extends VBox
{
    private double cost;
    private Text text;
    private CheckBox checkbox1, checkbox2, checkbox3, checkbox4, checkbox5, checkbox6;
    public PizzaMenu()
    {
        cost=10.00;
        text=new Text("Pizza Cost:" + cost);
        checkbox1 = new CheckBox("Extra Cheese");
        checkbox1.setOnAction(this::processCheckBox);
        checkbox2 = new CheckBox("Green Pepper");
        checkbox2.setOnAction(this::processCheckBox);
        checkbox3 = new CheckBox("Pepperoni");
        checkbox3.setOnAction(this::processCheckBox);
        checkbox4 = new CheckBox("Onion");
        checkbox4.setOnAction(this::processCheckBox);
        checkbox5 = new CheckBox("Sausage");
        checkbox5.setOnAction(this::processCheckBox);
        checkbox6 = new CheckBox("Anchovies");
        checkbox6.setOnAction(this::processCheckBox);
        //layout container 4 hbox, 2 vbox?
        HBox hSet1 = new HBox(checkbox1, checkbox2);
        hSet1.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        HBox hSet2 = new HBox(checkbox3, checkbox4);
        hSet2.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        HBox hSet3 = new HBox(checkbox5, checkbox6);
        hSet3.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        HBox userCost = new HBox(text);
        userCost.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        VBox vSet1 = new VBox(hSet1,hSet2,hSet3,userCost);
        vSet1.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        setSpacing(20);
        getChildren().addAll(vSet1);
    }
    public void processCheckBox(ActionEvent event)
    {
        if(checkbox1.isSelected() || checkbox2.isSelected() || checkbox3.isSelected() || checkbox4.isSelected() || checkbox5.isSelected() || checkbox6.isSelected())
        {
            cost = cost + 0.50;
            text.setText("Pizza Cost:" + cost);
        }
        else if(!checkbox1.isSelected() || !checkbox2.isSelected() || !checkbox3.isSelected() || !checkbox4.isSelected() || !checkbox5.isSelected() || !checkbox6.isSelected())
        {
            cost = cost - 0.50;
            text.setText("Pizza Cost:" + cost);
        }
    }
}
```

//updated

```
import javafx.scene.control.CheckBox;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;


public class PizzaMenu extends VBox
{
    private double cost;
    private Text text;
    private CheckBox checkbox1, checkbox2, checkbox3, checkbox4, checkbox5, checkbox6;
    public PizzaMenu()
    {
        cost=10.00;
        text=new Text("Pizza Cost:" + cost);
        checkbox1 = new CheckBox("Extra Cheese");
        checkbox1.setOnAction(this::processCheckBox);
        checkbox2 = new CheckBox("Green Pepper");
        checkbox2.setOnAction(this::processCheckBox);
        checkbox3 = new CheckBox("Pepperoni");
        checkbox3.setOnAction(this::processCheckBox);
        checkbox4 = new CheckBox("Onion");
        checkbox4.setOnAction(this::processCheckBox);
        checkbox5 = new CheckBox("Sausage");
        checkbox5.setOnAction(this::processCheckBox);
        checkbox6 = new CheckBox("Anchovies");
        checkbox6.setOnAction(this::processCheckBox);
        //layout container 4 hbox, 2 vbox?
        HBox hSet1 = new HBox(checkbox1, checkbox2);
        hSet1.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        HBox hSet2 = new HBox(checkbox3, checkbox4);
        hSet2.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        HBox hSet3 = new HBox(checkbox5, checkbox6);
        hSet3.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        HBox userCost = new HBox(text);
        userCost.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        VBox vSet1 = new VBox(hSet1,hSet2,hSet3,userCost);
        vSet1.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        setSpacing(20);
        getChildren().addAll(vSet1);
    }
    public void processCheckBox(ActionEvent event)
    {
//        if(checkbox1.isSelected() || checkbox2.isSelected() || checkbox3.isSelected() || checkbox4.isSelected() || checkbox5.isSelected() || checkbox6.isSelected())
//        {
//            cost = cost + 0.50;
//            text.setText("Pizza Cost:" + cost);
//        }
//        else if(!checkbox1.isSelected() || !checkbox2.isSelected() || !checkbox3.isSelected() || !checkbox4.isSelected() || !checkbox5.isSelected() || !checkbox6.isSelected())
//        {
//            cost = cost - 0.50;
//            text.setText("Pizza Cost:" + cost);
//        }
       if(event.getSource()==checkbox1)
       {
           if(checkbox1.isSelected())
           {
               cost = cost + 0.50;
               text.setText("Pizza Cost:" + cost);
           }
           else
           {
               cost = cost - 0.50;
               text.setText("Pizza Cost:" + cost);
           }
       }
        if(event.getSource()==checkbox2)
        {
            if(checkbox2.isSelected())
            {
                cost = cost + 0.50;
                text.setText("Pizza Cost:" + cost);
            }
            else
            {
                cost = cost - 0.50;
                text.setText("Pizza Cost:" + cost);
            }
        }
        if(event.getSource()==checkbox3)
        {
            if(checkbox3.isSelected())
            {
                cost = cost + 0.50;
                text.setText("Pizza Cost:" + cost);
            }
            else
            {
                cost = cost - 0.50;
                text.setText("Pizza Cost:" + cost);
            }
        }
        if(event.getSource()==checkbox4)
        {
            if(checkbox4.isSelected())
            {
                cost = cost + 0.50;
                text.setText("Pizza Cost:" + cost);
            }
            else
            {
                cost = cost - 0.50;
                text.setText("Pizza Cost:" + cost);
            }
        }
        if(event.getSource()==checkbox5)
        {
            if(checkbox5.isSelected())
            {
                cost = cost + 0.50;
                text.setText("Pizza Cost:" + cost);
            }
            else
            {
                cost = cost - 0.50;
                text.setText("Pizza Cost:" + cost);
            }
        }
        if(event.getSource()==checkbox6)
        {
            if(checkbox6.isSelected())
            {
                cost = cost + 0.50;
                text.setText("Pizza Cost:" + cost);
            }
            else
            {
                cost = cost - 0.50;
                text.setText("Pizza Cost:" + cost);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: unrelated: layouts are meant to be used (_not_ extended)

Answer (score 2):

problem is you're recalculating the whole price based on each and every checkbox, you should then start from the base cost on each action event:

```
public void processCheckBox(ActionEvent event)
{
    cost = 10.00;
    int toppings = checkbox1.isSelected() ? 1 : 0 +
                   checkbox2.isSelected() ? 1 : 0 +
                   checkbox3.isSelected() ? 1 : 0 +
                   checkbox4.isSelected() ? 1 : 0 +
                   checkbox5.isSelected() ? 1 : 0 +
                   checkbox6.isSelected() ? 1 : 0;
    cost = cost + (toppings * 0.50);
    text.setText("Pizza Cost:" + cost);
}
```

Comment: right thanks I have fixed it(I think) will update above the use of the ternary operator is cool thanks for the input!

Comment: you could also generify your update so you wouldn't need to increment the method if you add another checkbox using a simple cast:
public void processCheckBox(ActionEvent event)
{
    if ( ((CheckBox)event.getSource()).isSelected()) {
      cost = cost + 0.50;
    } else {
      cost = cost - 0.50;
    }
    text.setText("Pizza Cost:" + cost);
}